# Why are my camera tracking markings not in view of the camera?

Tags: camera, tracking

When I solve camera motion and set up tracking scene my camera does not point at the tracking markers. It also shifts the picture in the camera view down for some reason. The picture is not clipped in the tracking editor. I was not having this problem until a seemingly random resolve caused it.
[image: Problem]

Resolving the camera rotates the camera a little bit but the image is still clipped and the markers are still not centered.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was refining for optical center and it moved my optical center off screen. Resetting the optical center fixed the problem.